# Error injecting: org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo . java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/dependency/tree/DependencyTreeBuilder

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Sonar build failing with below error. I am using:

- sonar-maven-plugin-2.6,
- maven-3.0.3,
- sonarqube server - 3.4.1,
- Jenkins -1.574,
- sonar plugin- 2.1

Request to help me with below error, its blocking my release.

```
Error injecting: org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Lorg/apache/maven/shared/dependency/tree/DependencyTreeBuilder;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder

failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project;Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar failed: Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/dependency/tree/DependencyTreeBuilder;
```

Comment: When tried with sonar-maven-plugin-2.0, it failed saying - Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project;Can not execute Sonar. Then i tried with sonar-maven-plugin-2.6. Forgot to mention using JDK 8

Comment: Sonar(Qube) 3.4.1 is 4 years-old, it is not supported any longer. I suggest you upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: Thankyou Sir for response. What version of sonarqube compatible with below runnign versions????? Is it possible without upgrading sonarqube server instance, just upgrading plug-ins???As i mentioned we are now runnign with - sonar-maven-plugin-2.6,
maven-3.0.3,
sonarqube server - 3.4.1,
Jenkins -1.574,
sonar plugin- 2.1, JDK1.8.    Please help !!!!